# How to Display data horizontally

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have four tables (employees, allowances,deductions and Ajenda these are main tables , when i save employees financial details i save them in a different tables as image .
I want to display the employees detail and financial details in a horizontally way .
I'm using C# and SQLServer 2012 .
first table contains employees main details , second contain employees id with there allowances and other tables .

[My tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhweC.png)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What is your goal & your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, dev env & data structures, as well as to share more or less code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of screens, & user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: I have a solution if you make new posting.  There is no reason this posting should of been closed.  Nothing is missing.

Comment: Thus voted to reopen...

Comment: @Ragy Please give an example of the expected results, based on the table data you've provided. Also, is this WinForms or ASP.NET? Also, what have you researched or tried so far? Where exactly are you stuck? The request is quite broad and vague, we don't really know what part of the process is causing you difficulty. Are you struggling to write the necessary SQL query for example? Or struggling to bind the data to the UI? Or to create a UI that looks right? And/or something else? Please give clarity and details so we can target your help better.

Comment: @jdweng IMHO this post is far too vague and could easily be closed for lack of detail  / focus. As I've mentioned above we don't really know precisely what is required, or where the problem is with achieving it. There's not even an actual question here - just "I want"...a request for some vague to be created, seemingly from nothing. We don't even know what kind of C# app is being used. So I'm surprised you say you have a solution, because you'll have to make a lot of significant assumptions.

Comment: @Ragy P.S. I would also suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were recommended to do when you signed up for StackOverflow (but I can see from your profile that you haven't) and read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. That way you'll have a better idea of what a good question looks like, and then you can update yours to improve its quality, and therefore improve your chances of getting an answer. These resources are here to help you have a good experience on StackOverflow, so please use them. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my code before somebody closes it again.  I decided not to use group since there would be a lot of left outer joins which would complicate solution.  Decided just to create a table and then add the data directly to the results table.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable employees = new DataTable();
            employees.Columns.Add("empID", typeof(int));
            employees.Columns.Add("emp_name", typeof(string));
            employees.Columns.Add("emp_tele", typeof(string));

            employees.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "David", "025896325" });
            employees.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "John", "856985658" });
            employees.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Micheal", "654687887" });

            DataTable allowances = new DataTable();
            allowances.Columns.Add("empID", typeof(int));
            allowances.Columns.Add("allow_name", typeof(string));
            allowances.Columns.Add("allow_Amount", typeof(int));

            allowances.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "allow1", 100 });
            allowances.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "allow2", 200 });
            allowances.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "allow3", 300 });
            allowances.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "allow1", 100 });
            allowances.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "allow2", 200 });

            DataTable deductions = new DataTable();
            deductions.Columns.Add("empID", typeof(int));
            deductions.Columns.Add("Dedu_name", typeof(string));
            deductions.Columns.Add("Dedu_Amount", typeof(int));

            deductions.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "ded1", 10 });
            deductions.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "ded2", 5 });
            deductions.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "ded1", 10 });

            DataTable ajenda = new DataTable();
            ajenda.Columns.Add("empID", typeof(int));
            ajenda.Columns.Add("ajenda_name", typeof(string));
            ajenda.Columns.Add("ajenda_Amount", typeof(int));

            ajenda.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "aj1", 200 });
            ajenda.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "aj1", 200 });
            ajenda.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "aj2", 300 });

            DataTable results = employees.Clone();

            string[] allow_names = allowances.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("allow_name")).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
            foreach (string name in allow_names)
            {
                results.Columns.Add(name, typeof(string));
            }


            string[] dedu_names = deductions.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Dedu_name")).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
            foreach (string name in dedu_names)
            {
                results.Columns.Add(name, typeof(string));
            }

            string[] ajenda_names = ajenda.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("ajenda_name")).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
            foreach (string name in ajenda_names)
            {
                results.Columns.Add(name, typeof(string));
            }

            //add employees to result table
            foreach(DataRow row in employees.AsEnumerable())
            {
                results.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
            }

            var groupAllownaces = allowances.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("empID"));
            foreach (var group in groupAllownaces)
            {
                DataRow employeeRow = results.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("empID") == group.Key).First();
                foreach (DataRow row in group)
                {
                    employeeRow[row.Field<string>("allow_name")] = row.Field<int>("allow_Amount");
                }
            }

            var groupDeductions = deductions.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("empID"));
            foreach (var group in groupDeductions)
            {
                DataRow employeeRow = results.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("empID") == group.Key).First();
                foreach (DataRow row in group)
                {
                    employeeRow[row.Field<string>("Dedu_name")] = row.Field<int>("Dedu_Amount");
                }
            }

            var groupAjenda = ajenda.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("empID"));
            foreach (var group in groupAjenda)
            {
                DataRow employeeRow = results.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("empID") == group.Key).First();
                foreach (DataRow row in group)
                {
                    employeeRow[row.Field<string>("ajenda_name")] = row.Field<int>("ajenda_Amount");
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```